# PHP - Bytes to UTF8 character?

Tags: php, email, unicode, utf-8, utf

I need to process some emails and these contain character phrases such as:

```
=E2=82=AC
```

which apparently are the bytes for a euro sign.

I also get things such as:

```
VALIGN=3D"top"
```

which I'm not sure what that means (the 3D part).

And other such as :

```
FirstName=C2=A0LastName
```

Does anyone know how to convert this to the proper character via PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: This encoding is called *quoted-printable*.

Comment: It sounds like you're not processing the email properly.  The email system/api should be responsible for decoding that (quoted-printable encoding, =3D is an equal sign) before your code ever sees it.  How are you getting at the message body?

Comment: @MarkReed I need to parse it manually. Thanks for telling me about the encoding. Will see if that helps me any.

Comment: That's fine, but you don't need to write your own code from scratch to do it. Look at e.g. the Mail_MIME library.

Comment: Thanks @MarkReed I'll check that out! If you create an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll just delete or close this thread if it's of no relevance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gumbo pointed out, the characters are encoded as a quoted-printable string. To decode, use [this aptly named function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php):

```
$string = '=E2=82=AC';
echo quoted_printable_decode($string);
// echoes out €
```

But as MarkReed has pointed out, this isn't really a solution if your mail logic is flawed. Look into a robust e-mail framework or library if this functionality forms a large part of your app.